# How to get numbers array from entries that begins with certain text and ends only with numbers in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents like this stored in mongodb:

```
{
    name: "1234book"
}
{
    name: "book8"
}
{
    name: "book2"
}
{
    name: "book2some6text"
}
{
    name: "smallbook2some6text"
}
{
    name: "smallbook22"
}
```

How to get entries that begins with certain text and ends only with numbers?

**For example:**

str: "book"

**Expected result:**

```
{
    numbers: [8, 2]
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample Mongo document structure & the response format. Also provide proper criteria to get the appropriate result, for this string manipulation, because there may be several permutations possible. E.g. any fixed string length, any fixed string to be searched etc.

Comment: Try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html and show your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by firing this query:

```js
db.collection.find({name: {$regex: /^book(.*)[\d]$/}}).map(function(record){
  return NumberInt(record.name.match(/[\d]+$/)[0]);
});
```